# How to match MySQL FTS Query Results with LIKE wildcard Operators

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How to acheive the FTS returned results using LIKE Operator using wildcards. (But Not using RLIKE and REGEXP)

[Sample Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3fkS.png)

I tried with

%test% which returned all records in the table.

%test which returned all records except testing.

test% which returned only the record test.

I want to use only LIKE(not RLIKE and REGEX) and get the above result as "match(notecontent) against ('test');" returned.

Comment: LIKE cannot produce needed filtering.

Comment: You should not try to compare fulltext search and like result - these techniques work very differently from each other

Comment: Hi @Shadow Yes i can understand that but my use case is we have many databases. In one Database i have FTS support and in another database i dont have FTS support. The one in which i dont have FTS support i will query using LIKE and for FTS supported DB, fts Query will be applied. Both DB should return the same result. That is why i am matching FTS with LIKE

Comment: Then I suggest you to restructure your comment field if those hold comma delimited list of values as store each value as a row. You can easily use like or even exact match in.this case